# OpenCV Histogram Comparison Methods

Tags: opencv, image-processing, comparison, histogram

Looking at the [**Histogram Documentation**](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_comparison/histogram_comparison.html), there are 4(5) different comparison methods:

1. **CV_COMP_CORREL** *Correlation*
2. **CV_COMP_CHISQR** *Chi-Square*
3. **CV_COMP_INTERSECT** *Intersection*
4. **CV_COMP_BHATTACHARYYA** *Bhattacharyya distance*
5. **CV_COMP_HELLINGER** *Synonym for* **CV_COMP_BHATTACHARYYA**

They all give different outputs that are read differently as shown in the [**Compare Histogram Documentation**](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_comparison/histogram_comparison.html#results). But I can't find anything that states how effectively each method performs compared against each other. Surely there are Pros and Cons for each method, otherwise why have multiple methods?

Even the [**OpenCV 2 Computer Vision Application Programming Cookbook**](http://instructor.sdu.edu.kz/~konst/cv2012/books/OpenCV_2_Computer_Vision_Application_Programming_Cookbook.pdf) has very little to say on the differnces:

> The call to cv::compareHist is straightforward. You just input the two
>   histograms and the function returns the measured distance. The
>   specific measurement method you want to use is specified using a flag.
>   In the ImageComparator class, the intersection method is used **(with
>   flag CV_COMP_INTERSECT)**. This method simply compares, for each bin,
>   the two values in each histogram, and keeps the minimum one. The
>   similarity measure is then simply the sum of these minimum values.
>   Consequently, two images having histograms with no colors in common
>   would get an intersection value of 0, while two identical histograms
>   would get a value equal to the total number of pixels.
>
> The other methods available are the Chi-Square **(flag CV_COMP_CHISQR)**
>   which sums the normalized square difference between the bins, the
>   correlation method **(flag CV_COMP_CORREL)** which is based on the
>   normalized cross-correlation operator used in signal processing to
>   measure the similarity between two signals, and the Bhattacharyya
>   measure **(flag CV_COMP_BHATTACHARYYA)** used in statistics to estimate
>   the similarity between two probabilistic distributions.

There must be differences between the methods, so my question is what are they? and under what circumstances do they work best?

Comment: I would give wikipedia a try. It's like asking whether it's better to measure a distance in along the streets or as the crow flies... you might need to understand what you want to measure. But maybe there really is some kind of cooking book of "when to use which distance metric", so good luck with the question.

Comment: I just want some indication as to the differences there are in the methods available.

Answer (score 1):

CV_COMP_INTERSECT is fast to compute since you just need the minimum value for each bin. But it will not tell you much about the distribution of the differences. Other methods try to achieve better and more continuous score as a match, under different assumptions about the pixel distribution.

You can find the formulae used in different methods, at

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_comparison/histogram_comparison.html

Some references to more details on the matching algorithms can be found at:

http://siri.lmao.sk/fiit/DSO/Prednasky/7%20a%20Histogram%20based%20methods/7%20a%20Histogram%20based%20methods.pdf

Comment: Your first link was the same as my first link, but the second one was interesting. Having said that, it still only says as much as all the other links I've found: the scoring for the varying methods is done differently.

Comment: Mathematically speaking, a normalised histogram is a Probability density function (PDF). When we are matching two histograms, we are basically seeing how two distributions match each other. The best way to answer your question is to read text books on Statistical Pattern Recognition (Duda and Hart is pretty good), or publications like http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?rep=rep1&type=pdf&doi=10.1.1.154.8446 . I learned but forgot most of these stuff ;-(.

Comment: @Totoro the second link is not reachable anymore :(

Comment: Sorry about that, I never thought that Citeseer links could become inaccessible. The wikipedia page, while simple, has enough resources. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_matching